# image is not getting uploaded through nodeJs

Tags: node.js

I am uploading an image from nodeJs.

Control is not getting into `req.on('end')`. Nothing is getting printed inside `req.on('end')`. I could not identify where is the problem. I am making an API and calling from js to upload an image in the server at a specific location.

```
app.post('/tde/api/photo/:widgetId/:choosenFileName',function(req,res){
    console.log("In file Upload..");
    console.log(req.params.widgetId);
    console.log(req.params.choosenFileName);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/binary' });
    var filedata = '';
    var chunks = [];
    //req.setEncoding('binary');
    req.on('data', function(chunk){
        //filedata+= chunk;
        chunks.push(chunk);
    })
    req.on('end', function (chunk) {

            var dir = 'uploads/'+req.params.widgetId
            if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
                fs.mkdirSync(dir);
                console.log("directory created..");
            }
            fs.readdir(dir, function(err, filenames) {
                if (err) {
                  onError(err);
                  return;
                }
                filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
                    console.log(filename);
                    fs.unlink(dir+'/'+filename, function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.error(err);
                        }
                        console.log("File deleted successfully!");
                    });
                });
                //fs.writeFile('uploads/'+req.params.widgetId+'/sanmoy.jpg', chunk,  function(err) {
                var fileName = req.params.choosenFileName;
                var widgetId = req.params.widgetId;
                    //fs.writeFile('uploads/'+widgetId+'/'+fileName, filedata, 'binary', function(err) {
                var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)
                fs.writeFile('uploads/'+widgetId+'/'+fileName, buffer, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.error(err);
                    }
                    console.log("writing file success!");
                })  
            }); 

        });
    res.end("File is uploaded");
});
```

Comment: When I run your example with a console.log immediately inside the req.on('end') function, I get output, so control is getting there.  How are you calling this?

Comment: Is the file getting uploaded....dnt know mine is not getting into req.on('end')

Comment: Is the code running successfully.....from JavaScript I am calling the api..bt no folder is being created nor the file is getting uploaded..

Comment: Again, please show how you are calling the code.  Edit your question and add the relevant code.  Is the endpoint even being called?  Are you getting the first 3 console logs?

Comment: Yes it is getting called console.log(chunks) is getting printed inside req.on('data')

Comment: After that no log is getting printed....